# Expanding Divs on hover

Tags: html, css, web

Basically the idea is when the user hovers on a column, it will expand based on the given width. Much like this website http://outdatedbrowser.com/

Basically this is what i have done so far

```
<div class="columns col1"></div>
<div class="columns col2"></div>
<div class="columns col3"></div>
<div class="columns col4"></div>
<div class="columns col5"></div>


.columns{
    width:20%; 
    height:100%;
    float:left; 
    position:absolute; 
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s linear
}

.columns:hover{width:30%; overflow:visible; z-index:1}

.col1{background-color:#FC9526;}
.col2{background-color:#217C9D; left:20%}
.col3{background-color:#F9BD39; left:40%}
.col4{background-color:#5C5C8A; left:60%;}
.col5{background-color:#EA4A36; left:80%;}
```

at first I tried without using position:absolute, but the last column keeps on collapsing at the bottom. The problem with position absolute is that whenever I hover on the last column it will display a horizontal scroll bar. Is it possible to achieve this with only CSS

Comment: I believe you need javascript for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the 5th column left an extra 10% width:

```
.col5:hover{left:70%}
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/UKj5r/)

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer, the last thing that bothers me is that when hovering on other columns. Since the columns are set with z-index:1, it will not show the transition when resizing back to the original width

Comment: I think the part that was confusing in it was why a vertical scroll opened up. Had that not been the case it likely would have been more intuitive to solve.

Comment: vertical? I think it was horizontal scroll :)

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken. I was just referring to what might have confused too, not what the problem was. Here's a screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/n3f7P/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.col1{background-color:#FC9526;}
.col2{background-color:#217C9D; left:20%}
.col3{background-color:#F9BD39; left:40%}
.col4{background-color:#5C5C8A; left:60%;}
.col5{background-color:#EA4A36; left:80%;}
```

Add this line of code to your css and it will work perfectly

```
.col5:hover{left:70%}
```